# ajax: Post method not working when included in a "switch"

Tags: ajax, post, switch-statement

Working on a chat ajax based.
I have a postmessage() function that works as intended.

```
function postmessage()
    {
        var message =   document.getElementById("message_area").value;
        message = message.trim();
        if (message.length == 0) return;
        if (message.charAt (0) == '/')
        {
            processIrcCommand(message);
            return;
        }
        
        
        
        data = 
            {
            "action" : "send",
            "message" : message,
            };
        
        $.post('chat.php',data, function(response)
        {
            if( response == 'posted' )
            {
                $('.message_input').val(''); 
            }
        });
            
        
    }
```

As you can see in the code am now tyring to implement an Irc command system.

here is the function :

```
function processIrcCommand (inputText) 
{
    
    var ircCommandArray = inputText.match (/^\/([a-z?]+)\s*(.*)/);
    if (!ircCommandArray)   return;
    var ircCommand = ircCommandArray[1];
    var quotedString = ircCommandArray[2].match (/"(.*)"/);
    if (quotedString == null)
        var ic_more = ircCommandArray[2].match (/(\S*)\s*(.*)/);
    else
        var ic_more = ircCommandArray[2].match (/"(.*)"\s*(.*)/);
    
    
    switch (ircCommand) 
    {
        case "debug":
          alert('code working');
          $('.message_input').val('');
        break; 

        case "me":
            
            data = 
            {
            "action" : "sendme",
            "message" : message,
            };
        
            $.post('chat.php',data, function(response)
            {
                if( response == 'posted' )
                {
                    $('.message_input').val(''); 
                }
            });
          break;
        
        case "quit":
        case "logout":
            location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
        break;
        
        
    }
}
```

here are my different attemps:

1. to make sure that the post "chat.php?action=sendme" was working as intended, I debuged it through the function postmessage(); by changing the action from "send" to "sendme".
   everything worked fine.
2. then i started to debug my function processIrcCommand(); step by step using alert(); to make sure.
   As you can see there are 3 cases.
   The logout case and debug case works fine.
   The "me case is my issue.

I try the case, outside of the "switch", the function works perfectly... but not in the switch.
any clue?

and my apologies if the problem seems trivial, i just started coding a few months back.. learning php, and trying to get deeper, i had to use ajax on the fly.
thank you for you understanding.

Comment: Hi, you can call some function inside `me` case and there write your ajax call there.. see if that works or not .

Comment: @Swati, I am not quite sure i follow (sorry english isn't my native language.
the function postMessage() , include the function processIrcCommand, which then include the post inside the me...

Comment: Hi, i am saying put `$.post('chat.php',data, function(response)` in some function and then called that function `me` case i.e : `callyourfn()`

Comment: ok, this was not better, but allowed me to find the bug. 
when moving under the function 'processIRCcommand, i was not transfering the parameter "message Value", so i was posting, and empty variable... which make it stops working. 
Passing over "Message.val()" it now works. 
Thank you :)